# VBA to Refresh Query Data on Protected Page, works when stepped through, fails run automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table which is populated through a query.  The sheet is protected.  In order to refresh the table from the query I've written a small code to unprotect the sheet, refresh the query/data and then reprotect the sheet.

The issue I'm running into is that it will successfully run and refresh the query/data when the macro is stepped through, however when initiated from a command button or manually pressing the play macro button, it fails telling me that it's trying to update a protected worksheet.

```
Private Sub cb_RefreshData_Click()
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="mypassword"
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - myQuery").Refresh
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=9 _
    , Criteria1:="="
Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="mypassword"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to turn off "refresh query in the background"...facepalm.